# Angular Application Design Problem with spinner and autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, spinner

I wish to call an API Rest that returns a Json to me. Once the JSON is retrieved, the goal is to use a self-completion system. During autocompletion I want a spinner to be displayed until the end of the get.

Currently the autocomplete works perfectly but each time I wanted to integrate the spinner, I had problems, when defining an "isLoading" variable I had to define it in both the Service class and the ServicesNamespaceComponent class.

So I think there is a design problem.
If a person can show me an example of how to improve my code to integrate this spinner in a simple way in the getData method

```
services-namespace.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RestApiService } from '../shared/rest-api.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, startWith, debounceTime, switchMap, map, filter, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
  
export class Service {
  constructor(private dataService: RestApiService) {}
  
  namespaces = [];
  

  getData(){
    return this.namespaces.length ?
    of(this.namespaces) :
    this.dataService.getAllNameSpaces();
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-services-namespace',
  templateUrl: './services-namespace.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services-namespace.component.scss']
})




export class ServicesNamespaceComponent implements OnInit {

  
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private service: Service) {
     this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(val => {
            return this.filter(val || '')
       }) 
    )
   }

  ngOnInit() {
   
  }

  filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
    // call the service which makes the http-request
    return this.service.getData()
     .pipe(
       map(response => response.filter(option => { 
         return option.namespace.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
       }))
     )
   }  







}
```

```
services-namespace.component.html
 <!--  <mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"
    color="primary" 
    mode="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-spinner> 
-->
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
<mat-progress-bar mode="buffer"></mat-progress-bar>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.namespace">
        {{option.namespace}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the isLoading property in the component and then set it to true in the filter() method before the first return and then set it to false  before the second return in the map operator.